# Using pyarrow to stream an openCV image to multiple processes

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, pyarrow

I´m using openCV in python to load a video stream from a camera.  I need to do multiple processing jobs on this stream, so, for instance, I might want to find objects in the image, do edge detection, color changes, etc, all on the same stream.  I´d like to do it in parallel in many processes.  The easiest solution would be to pickle the image frames and send them to all the processes, but for a high quality video this can be very costly.

I would like to read a frame, store this frame in memory with pyarrow and then have every process access this same frame in memory to do its trick. Then read another frame, etc.  Couple of problems: i) how to access the frame from all processes with pyarrow (I understand from the docs that this should be possible, could not figure how); ii) how to make sure that all processes are done with the frame before overwriting it with another frame.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. [Plasma](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/plasma.html) might be a good place to start for sharing the data.
2. Image replacement/deletion with distributed workers.  There isn't one answer to this and any solution will have tradeoffs.  You might try using something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) as a starting point.